# Unable to place figure side by side and footnote in beamer class using caption

Tags: beamer

Hello friends i have a problem in placing a figure side by side in beamer class and footnotes is shown in numeral while it showing as alphabet i want footnote as numeral value. Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[10pt,numbered]{beamer}
 \mode<presentation>

 \definecolor{dipjyoticol}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.641}
 \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=dipjyoticol}
 %\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

 %\usetheme{Singapore}
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
 %\usetheme{Madrid}
 %\usetheme{Boadilla}
 %\usetheme{Berkeley}
 %\usetheme{Antibes}
 %\usetheme{AnnArbor}
 %\usetheme{Copenhagen}
 %\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
 \usepackage{cite,graphicx}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{pstricks,colortab,pifont}
 \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
 \usebeamerfont{child}
 \usepackage{caption}
 %\usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 %\usepackage{psfrag}
 %\usepackage{url}
 %\usepackage{stfloats}
 %\usepackage{array}
 %\usepackage{multirow}
 %\usepackage{newlfont}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 %\usepackage{amsfonts}
 %\usepackage{amsmath}
 %\usepackage{amssymb}
 %\usepackage{cases}
 %\usepackage{subfig}
 %\usepackage{subfigure}
 %\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=50pt}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{mdwlist}
 %\usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
 \usepackage{float}
 %\usepackage{algorithm,tabularx,stfloats}
 %\usepackage{ulem}
 %\usepackage{theorem}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 %\usepackage{inputenc}
 %\usepackage{times}
 %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 %\usepackage{multimedia}
 %\usepackage[draft]{pgf}
 %\usepackage{gensymb}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
 \usetikzlibrary{shadows}


 %\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
 %\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
 %\usecolortheme{blue}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
 \newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\bo}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath$ {#1} $}}
 %\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
 \title{ Name of the Title}

 \author{ Presented by:{\textbf{Author Name}} \\Supervisor:{\textbf{supervisor name}} \\~\\ \vspace{2mm}
     Name of Department \\ABC Institute of Technology}
 \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.6in, width=0.6in]{example-image-b}}
 \date{\tiny {\today}}
 %**********************
 \useoutertheme{sidebar}
 \makeatletter
   \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
   {
     \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
     \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
     \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
     \vfill
     \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
     \else%
       \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
       \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
       \vskip2pt%
     \fi%
 }%
 %\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
 %{
 %    \nointerlineskip
 %    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=1.8em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
 %        \vbox{}\vskip-2ex%
 %        \strut\insertframetitle\strut
 %        \vskip-0.8ex%
 %    \end{beamercolorbox}
 %}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
 \tikzset{
     tangent/.style={
         decoration={
             markings,% switch on markings
             mark=
                 at position #1
                 with
                 {
                \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
            }
    },
    postaction=decorate
     },
     use tangent/.style={
    shift=(tangent point-#1),
    x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
    y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
     },
     use tangent/.default=1
 }
 \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
 \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
    \makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
\makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \titlepage
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
 \newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
    >{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%

 \begin{frame}{Outline}
 %\frametitle{Outline}
 %\scriptsize
 \footnotesize
 \tableofcontents
 %\begin{itemize}
 %\item
 %\end{itemize}
 \end{frame}


 \section{Chapter 1: Introduction}

 \begin{frame}{Introduction}
 \begin{minipage}{8cm}
 \begin{figure}
 \caption*{First Device\footnote{\tiny{abc} \textit{bcde} \textbf{1987, 51, 913-915.}}}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}
 \end{figure}
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}{12cm}
 \begin{figure}
 \caption*{First Time\footnote{\tiny{xyz} \textit{absfg,} \textbf{1990, 347 }}}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-b}
 \end{figure}
 \end{minipage}\hfill       

 \end{frame}


 \end{document}
```

Here is the output of my MWE

[image]

Comment: You should really clean up your preamble, many of the packages are unnecessary. graphicx, color ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\definecolor{dipjyoticol}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.641}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=dipjyoticol}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{caption}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}

\begin{document}


\section{Chapter 1: Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
         \begin{figure}
             \caption*{First Device\footnotemark[1] }
             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
         \end{figure}
     \end{column}
     \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
         \begin{figure}
             \caption*{First Time\footnotemark[2]}
             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
         \end{figure}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\footnotetext[1]{\tiny{abc} \textit{bcde} \textbf{1987, 51, 913-915.}}
\footnotetext[2]{\tiny{xyz} \textit{absfg,} \textbf{1990, 347 }}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @BikiTeron You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

an alternative, without footnotes ... (maybe you liked it :-) )

```
 \documentclass[10pt,numbered]{beamer}
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
 \useoutertheme{sidebar}
 \makeatletter
   \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
   {
     \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
     \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
     \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
     \vfill
     \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
     \else%
       \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
       \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
       \vskip2pt%
     \fi%
 }%
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.48\linewidth}
 \begin{figure}
 \caption{First Device}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
                {\tiny{abc} \textit{bcde} \textbf{1987, 51, 913-915.}}
\end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.48\linewidth}
 \begin{figure}
 \caption{First Time}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
                {\tiny{xyz} \textit{absfg,} \textbf{1990, 347 }}
 \end{figure}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter, deleted. i forgot to delete it  when copy op question :-(.

Comment: Don't worry, you managed to remove 98% of the unnecessary packages - that's a good success rate :)

Comment: @samcarter, you so nice person! of course and very knowledge too!

Comment: Thank you, but you are the knowledgeable amongst us, soon you will reach 100000 reputation!