# How should i properly arrange these in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I was not able to find out the correct coding to place two figures vertically in right column, on left column itemize environment with figures Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}


 \definecolor{dipjyoticol}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.641}
 \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=dipjyoticol}

 \usetheme{Warsaw}
 \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}


 \title{ Name of the Title}

 \author{ Presented by:{\textbf{Author Name}} \\Supervisor:{\textbf{supervisor name}} \\~\\ \vspace{2mm}
    Name of Department \\ABC Institute of Technology}
 \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.6in, width=0.6in]{example-image-b}}
 \date{\tiny {\today}}
 %**********************
 \useoutertheme{sidebar}

 \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}{abcdefgshwttt gsshshshs1}
     \begin{minipage}{5cm}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item \small It was observed that the maximum brightness value of ABCDE (device B1) improves significantly to 0000 $cd/m^{2}$ as compared to 1111 $cd/m^{2}$ of PFO (more than $n$ times).
          \end{itemize}
          \begin{figure}
               \includegraphics[scale=0.20]{example-image-a}
               \caption{\small Voltage vs Current Density (LE-J) curves of PFO and ABCDE based hole only and electron only devices, Film thickness=00nm}
          \end{figure}
     \end{minipage}\hfill
     \begin{minipage}{5cm}
          {\small\fontdimen2\font=1pt Device structure:ABC/ABCDE:SSS(00nm)/ polymer(00nm)/CiF(0.0nm)/Cl(000nm)}
     \begin{columns}
           \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
                (a).\begin{figure}
                    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
                \end{figure}
           \end{column}
     \end{columns}
     \begin{columns}
          \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
            (b).  
            \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Brightness vs. Current Density (B-J) (a) and Current Density vs. Voltage (J-V) (b) curves of the single layer Blue PLEDs.}
            \end{figure}

          \end{column}
      \end{columns}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use the beamer columns environment (as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414381/36296), maybe with `\begin{columns}[T]`

Comment: And please update your author, date and logo definitions, see @Zarkos comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414385/how-to-write-text-in-title-slide-of-beamer-class-in-top-rectangular-blue/414387?noredirect=1#comment1035107_414387